# CLR Trigger exception when try to communicate with a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, triggers, sqlclr

I have a CLR SQL Trigger, that tries to communicate with a WCF service on the basis of the following [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21149/Invoking-a-WCF-Service-from-a-CLR-Trigger)

When I try to update/insert a record, I get the following exception:

```
No row was updated.    
The data in row 1 was not committed.    
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.    
Error Message: A .NET Framework error occured during execution of a user-defined routine or aggregate "WCFTrigger": System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempt to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.    
The protected resource (only available with full trust) where: All    
The demanded resources were: Synchronization, ExternalThreading    
System.Security.HostProtectionException:    
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(Type ContactType, Type ServiceType, Object serviceImplementation)    
  at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory '1.CreateDescription()    
  at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(Binding binding, 
EndpointAddress address)    
  at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory '1..ctor(Binding binding, EndpointAddress address)    
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase '1..ctor(Binding binding, EndpointAddress address)    
  at ServiceClient.WCFServiceReference.ServiceContractClient..ctor(Binding binding, 
EndpointAddress address)
```

The host is just like in the article, the client's `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceContract" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/services/MyService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IServiceContract" contract="WCFServiceReference.IServiceContract" name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceContract">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="xxx@yyy.zzzt"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

Has anybody any idea, what is that and why?

---

The code of the trigger:

```
public partial class Triggers {
    [SqlProcedure()]
    public static void SendData( String crudType ) {
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress( new Uri( "http://localhost:8000/services/myservice" ) );
        WSHttpBinding httpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
        ServiceClient.WCFServiceReference.ServiceContractClient  myClient = new ServiceClient.WCFServiceReference.ServiceContractClient( httpBinding, endpoint );

            switch( crudType ) {
                case "Update":
                    myClient.UpdateOccured();
                    break;
                case "Insert":
                    myClient.InsertOccured();
                    break;
        }
    }

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlTrigger( Name = "WCFTrigger",
       Target = "tbCR", Event = "FOR UPDATE, INSERT" )]
    public static void Trigger1() {
        SqlTriggerContext myContext = SqlContext.TriggerContext;

        switch( myContext.TriggerAction ) {
            case TriggerAction.Update:
                SendData( "Update" );
                break;
            case TriggerAction.Insert:
                SendData( "Insert" );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The proxy:

```
namespace ServiceClient.WCFServiceReference {
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="WCFServiceReference.IServiceContract")]
    public interface IServiceContract {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IServiceContract/UpdateOccured", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IServiceContract/UpdateOccuredResponse")]
        void UpdateOccured();

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IServiceContract/InsertOccured", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IServiceContract/InsertOccuredResponse")]
        void InsertOccured();
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface IServiceContractChannel : ServiceClient.WCFServiceReference.IServiceContract, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class ServiceContractClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ServiceClient.WCFServiceReference.IServiceContract>, ServiceClient.WCFServiceReference.IServiceContract {

        public ServiceContractClient() {
        }

        public ServiceContractClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public ServiceContractClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public ServiceContractClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public ServiceContractClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public void UpdateOccured() {
            base.Channel.UpdateOccured();
        }

        public void InsertOccured() {
            base.Channel.InsertOccured();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused running .NET code (WCF client calling service) in SQL Server under a partial trust code access security (CAS) setting. Look at the this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx) on configuring CAS for SQL Server.

EDIT:

As an alternative to enabling full trust, configure a webHttpBinding endpoint on the WCF service. Call the service using the System.Net [HttpWebRequest & HttpWebResponse](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303436) classes to avoid using the WCF ChannelFactory based plumbing.

Comment: It could be that, but the error says that the code requires full trust which is not possible in SQL CLR.  Usually calling a web service requires EXTERNAL permission for the assembly and database owner, but you don't get the exception reported here if that is the problem.

Comment: I've changed the "Permission Level" of the Trigger-project to Unsafe, but there is no any change

Comment: I believe the root of the issue may be that WCF is dynamically creating assemblies to act as the service proxies. That may be why this code needs a full trust environment. If SQLCLR can't be configured for full trust (I don't know much about SQLCLR) then you won't be able to run the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything multithreaded in any SQLCLR assemblies and the exception is telling you that you are trying to use threading.  Are you calling the WCF service asynchronously?

I would reccomend posting your code from the SQLCLR trigger for more help.

Calling WCF services from SQL CLR is much more difficult that calling asmx web services, are you sure you need wcf?

Comment: No, in the "Service Reference Settings" the "Generate asynchronous operations" is not checked, and from the trigger I call the "SendData" synchronously!

Comment: "The demanded resources were: Synchronization, ExternalThreading"  seems to indicate something in your code or the generated proxies is trying to do something multi-threaded.  Last time i tried to consume WCF via a SQL CLR trigger i just gave up and created a asmx web service and it worked a treat.  Is this an option, also please post your trigger code.

Comment: Hmm on further inspection it might be something to do with your wcf service rather than your SQL CLR trigger as the error seems to occur not in your trigger but in WCF service.  Can you call the service from  a simple console application?